# WPF ListBox виснет при смене ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, .net-core

Тестовое окно с разметкой

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button
        Height="30"
        Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"
        Content="load"/>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}" Height="500"/>
</StackPanel>
```

по клику заполняем список

```
public IList<string> Items { get; private set; }

private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var list = new List<string>(13000);
    for (var i = 0; i < 13000; i++) list.Add($"line {i}");
    Items = list;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
}
```

все работает очень быстро и отнимает 4 мегабайта памяти.

Пытаюсь переопределить шаблон в ресурсах тестового окна.Вот [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/listbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) описан дефолтный шаблон. Копирую его с себе (только часть для ListBox). Заменяю все привязки цветов на заглушки и запускаю.

И получаю взрывной рост потребления памяти, GC просто сходит с ума и в итоге даже мышь начинает тормозить и приходится убивать приложение.

Даже если оставить самый минимум.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                    <Border
                        Name="Border"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        CornerRadius="2">
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0" Focusable="false">
                            <StackPanel Margin="2" IsItemsHost="True" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Не помогает.

Смотрел дельту снапшотов памяти - там ничего не понятно. То взрывной рост каких то List, то WeakReference сотнями тысяч

Что я делаю не так? Это не может быть баг, ведь не я первый додумался сменить шаблон контрола.
Воспроизводится на net48 и netcore3.1

Так в чем же дело?

update: добавил скрин из VS

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дело не в виртуализации? Не отваливается она?

Comment: @АндрейNOP видимо не слишком точно описал. Оно не "просто лагает". Это начинается сразу после обновления источника. Причем список таки может появиться (но тормоза не уйдут), но чаще приходится уже убивать ибо мышь в системе лагает. Сделал скрин, но в самом начале процесса. Слева без шаблона - там список появляется сразу, а справа в начале процесса иначе потом все висит и скрин не сделать.

Comment: Ну а что с виртуализацией-то?

Comment: @АндрейNOP я не понимаю вопроса. До появления списка может пройти полминуты и при этом комп может повиснуть. Даже если виртуализация не работает - оно не может повесить комп.  Ну а если вы про VirtualizingStackPanel как ItemsPanel, то никакого эффекта.

Comment: Зачем вам 13000 элементов? Они никогда не влезут в экран (если это конечно не пиксели, но для пикселей я бы использовал другое хранилище). Используйте DefaultView и фильтруйте, можно постранично, можно догружать по скроллу. Какова практическая ценность этого теста?

Comment: @aepot Не стоит придумывать себе проблем на ровном месте. 13тыс элементов нужны, занимают всего 4 метра оперативы, абсолютно не тормозят. Все хорошо, пока я не решил поменять цвет ListBox и вот тогда обнаружил, что смена шаблона вешает буквально все. При пользовательском шаблоне даже 1000 элементов появляется дольше и жрет в 10 раз больше памяти, чем 13тыс элементов без своего шаблона. Но мой то шаблон ничем не отличается от дефолтного - я же его с сайта майков и взял.

Comment: Потом, я бы использовал `ItemsPanelTemplate`, а внутри `VirtualizingStackPanel`, а вашу `StackPanel` в шаболне заменил бы на `<ItemsPresenter/>`.

Comment: @aepot ItemsPresenter решает проблему. Но вопрос тот же - почему не тормозит дефолтный шаблон, но тормозит, когда этот же дефолтный шаблон я задаю сам? Да не просто тормозит, а буквально вешает систему.

Comment: Ну т.е. всё-таки проблема в виртуализации, как я изначально предполагал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следует использовать следующее:

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="0" Focusable="false">
    <ItemsPresenter />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Мне кажеться что просто ради того что бы продемострировать возможности `WPF`. В статье, для того что бы не нагружать читателя, использовали `StackPanel`. Потому что `StackPanel` это универсальная вещь, которая может помочь везде и всегда. Вариативности у использования `StackPanel` очень много.

Следует заметить что сложные контролы требуют немного другого подхода. Так что для больших листов следует использовать `ItemsPresenter`.

Кстати если капнуть еще глубже, то окажется что у `ListBox` по дефолту стоит `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing = True`. А если еще пойти дальше - то можно найти как работает ItemsPresenter с виртуализацией - [referencesource ItemsPresenter](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/ItemsPresenter.cs). Следовательно Вы заведомо, точнее автор статьи, использует как холдер для элементов контрол без стандартной виртулизации, поэтому на больших коллекциях и идет просадка. А в обычной реализации стиля `ListBox` используется `ItemsPresenter`.

Так что. Лучше в данном случае использовать `ItemsPresenter`! А бага никакого нет. Просто статья обзорная.

UPD. поигрался еще.
Можно вместо `StackPanel`, как показано в статье, использовать `VirtualizingStackPanel`:

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="0" Focusable="false">
    <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True"></VirtualizingStackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Проблем с `VirtualizingStackPanel` не наблюдается!

А вот теперь давайте выключим у `ListBox` значение - `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVritualizing`. При этом будем использовать `VirtualizingStackPanel`. :

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBox">
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                        <Border
                            Name="Border"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            CornerRadius="2">
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="0" Focusable="false">
                                <VirtualizingStackPanel  IsItemsHost="True"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

А вот теперь просадки есть, как будто мы используем простой `StackPanel`, как в статье.

Comment: Сложно сказать, какую цель преследовал автор, ведь в той же статье во 2 абзаце (ListBox Parts) написано, что нужно использовать ItemsPresenter. Но в самом шаблоне его нет, а ведь именно это и расходится по инету (я видел это в ответах на SO пока искал шаблоны). Меня смутило, что я не вижу ItemsPresenter, но я первый раз перегружаю шаблон именно ListBox и "ну майкам же виднее, они же дефолтный шаблон делали". Хотелось бы узнать еще ответы на вопросы: 1) почему же оно ТАК тормозит, что комп колом стает? 2) где же брать настоящие дефолтные шаблоны?

Comment: @vitidev так тормозит из-за того что отключена виртуализация. прочтитайте пожалуйста про виртуализацию сами. если сравнивать winforms и wpf, то у wpf используется другой способ рендеринга и он более гибкий. а если более гибкий - то значит более затратный. то есть он пытается за один раз все сразу отрисовать, даже то чего нет в вашем поле зрения. а виртуализация она как бы учитывает скоуп - сколько элементов можно отобразить за раз!
брать шаблоны - исследовать самому, например такой утилитой как Snooper. в свое время ей я пользовался и писал свои собственные шаблоны.

Comment: @vitidev повторю - статья обзорная. это не призыв к действию. по интернету много чего расходится. но я дал выдержку из referencesource - ListBox прямо там кричит о том что он работает с виртуализацией. ну и кстати статья хорошая и остальные статьи по теме своих кастомных шаблонов WPF. не стоит снимать со счетов ее. просто автор предложил такой вариант решения. бывает.

Comment: Как по мне, ответ исчерпывающий, практически тоже самое я хотел написать, но автор ответа меня опередил.